# AngularJS: Code worked in Controller but not in factory: Possibly unhandled rejection: {}

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After building the Web API, I just promoted a controller to a service (.factory) to share that data with other controllers in AngularJS. 
However it seems that I have a syntax error and the factory is not accepted as it.

This is my App.js:

```
//appContacts.js

(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("appContacts", ["simpleControls", 'ui.router', 'ngResource'])
        .config(a lot of stuff here)

        .factory('ContactService', function ($resource) {

            var ContactService = {};
            var vm = this;
            vm.contacts = [];
            vm.newContact = {};
            vm.errorMessage = "";
            vm.isBusy = true;

            // Load all contacts  
            ContactService.getContacts = function () {
                return $resource.get("api/contacts")
                    .then(function (response) {
                        angular.copy(response.data, vm.contacts);
                    }
                );
            };

            //Set Current Contact
            ContactService.setCurrentContact = function (contact) {
                vm.currentContact = contact;
                return vm.currentContact;
            };
            return ContactService;
        })
})();
```

and this is my contatcsController:

```
//contactsController.js

(function () {
     "use strict";
     angular.module("appContacts")
        .controller("contactsController", function (ContactService) {

            //Get all Contacts
        ContactService.getContacts = function () {
            vm.contacts = contacts;
        }

        vm.setCurrentContact = function (contact) {
            vm.currentContact = contact;
        };
    })
})();
```

I keep getting this error: **Possibly unhandled rejection: {}** in the Console and nothing shows in the front end.
Does anybody has an idea why it does not work as factory the same code that worked inside the controller?

Comment: What did you mean with `vm`? Is it the `ViewModel`? The *viewModel* context is a property of a component controller, so, factory cannot have `var vm = this`.

Comment: please check this link it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931983/angularjs-possible-unhandled-rejection-when-using-ui-router

Answer (score 0):

More details at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2889

```
app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);
```