# AngularJS possible unhandled rejection when using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

After I have changed from ngRoute to angular-ui-router the console shows always 4 errors stating: **Possibly unhandled rejection: {}**

I did not noticed any "problem" in the behavior of the application I am building, but I would like to get rid of it.

Any idea what does it mean and how to solve it?

Here an screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please refer: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2699 or https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2889

Comment: Thanks after reading the links I have downgraded the angular from 1.58 to the 1.4.1 and now the error dissapeared

Answer (score 22):

This issue is found in 1.5.9 and 1.6.0-rc-0. 
More details at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2889

Patch solution is to manually disable unhandled rejections.

```
app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);
```

Comment: But isn't debugging phantom exception errors just that much more fun??

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Was struggling after upgrading from 1.4.4 to 1.7.7

Comment: So, you suggest to suppress all errors? Including the real ones? Have fun debugging those. This is dangerous advice and ought not to have been upvoted, let alone so often.

Comment: This advice was given 3.5 years ago, when this issue suddenly caused many production upgrade errors. The proper overall approach is to work through addressing the causes of the error message, while using the bandaid suppression in production in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I used the next solution

```
    $http.get('/api/get').then(function(result) {
       // ... stuff here
    }).catch(angular.noop);
```

it's equals to

```
$http.get('/api/get').then(function(result) {
  // ... stuff here
}).catch(function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the logic for uiCanExit in angular-ui-router file(I'm using v1.0.16), it checks only for resolved promise but not for a rejected promise. It is something like:

```
promise.then(function (val) { 
    return val !== false ? next_transition : current_transition
});
```

Just return a resolved promise with false value to cancel transition.
e.g.,

```
defer.resolve(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the promise with false if you are trying to abort a transition.