# How to prevent state change in AngularJS 1.6 with ui-router 1.0?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, transition, angularjs-1.6

How can we use `$transitions` to cancel a state change to prompt the user for saving? Previous ui-router versions used to have an `event` in the callback, and could be stopped with `event.preventDefault()`, but this event seems to have disappeared.

I'm using this code in my controller:

```
var onTransitionStartOff = $transitions.onStart({}, function($transitions)
{
    if ($scope.itemTracker.hasChanged()) {
        $scope.itemTracker.askExitConfirm().then(function () {
            onTransitionStartOff();
            var toState = $transitions.$to();
            $state.go(toState);
        }, function () {});
        return $q.reject(null);
    }
    onTransitionStartOff();
});
```

It works great, but it leaves an error message in the console due to the rejected promise.

[image: console error]

I took a look in stateService.ts, but I didn't see some interesting things...

Comment: Check out my suggestion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931983/angularjs-possible-unhandled-rejection-when-using-ui-router/40366492#40366492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to resolve the promise with false if you want to stay in the current state or true if you want to navigate to the new state.

```
return $q.resolve(false);
```

Comment: Returning false or null works, but it prints an error to the console, that's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: I'm sorry, I read too fast, the trick was to *resolve* and not to *reject* the promise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [using `uiCanExit()` on your controller](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1controller.html#uicanexit)

```
app.component('myComponent', {
  template: '<input ng-model="$ctrl.data" type="text">',
  bindings: { 'data': '<' },
  controller: function() {

    this.originalData = angular.copy(this.data);

    this.uiCanExit = function() {
      if (!angular.equals(this.data, this.originalData) {
        // Note: This could also return a Promise and request async
        // confirmation using something like ui-bootstrap $modal
        return window.confirm("Data has changed.  Exit anyway and lose changes?");
      }
    }
  }
```

This can also handle asynchronous code (return a promise).